# How to parse unrecognizable argument?

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

for my program I need to parse one .xml file and one .ttf file. I don't want to bother the user by typing the argument's id but I would rather accept the parsed data and then decide which file is which based on .extension. Is it possible with argparser to do something like

```
py -3 file.py "C/documents/file.xml" "C/documents/font.ttf"
```

in unknown order and decide after receiving paths to the files? I just need to know how to parse such informations into the Python program without interupting it. Thanks

Comment: What are you asking here? What "interrupting" are you talking about? You can do `if param.endswith('xml')`, for example.

Comment: Another option could be to just iterate over `sys.argv` and check using `.endswith('.xml')`

Answer (score 0):

After receiving the inputs from the user, assuming their paths are in `var1` and `var2`, just check the extensions using `var1.split(".")[1]` and `var2.split(".")[1]` (they return the *string after the point*, which is your **file extension**) and do something like this (assuming the user didn't put two files with the same extension)

```
if var1.split(".")[1] == "xml"
 xml_file=var1
 ttf_file=var2
else:
 xml_file=var2
 ttf_file=var1
```

Comment: I wanted to know hwo to parse it. I don't understand Daniel Roseman's comment, but Ralf, pointed out nicely that it can be done with sys.argv, I was focused on searching solution relation to argparse, but I don't know how to do this with this module

Comment: I would recommend for your code to use split('.')[-1], you can't know how many dots can be in the path. Which is the same as endswith. If the path is C/master.on.xml/documents/file.xml, then you have a problem

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Ralf in comments under my question I came to solution

```
args = sys.argv[1:] #the first one is path of your python script
if len(args) > 3:
    print('wrong')

for i in args:
    if i.endswith('.xml'):
        xml_path = i
    if i.endswith('.ttf'):
        font_path = i
```

Comment: Note that if you pass more than one xml name, the last will win, and the others will be silently ignored. It's easy to fix with a check for `xml_path is None` before assignment, and signal an error.

Comment: you are right, thanks. I though that it would be solved with len(args) but two .xml could be parsed and it would go through it as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom action. The call to `delattr` feels a bit iffy to me, but keeps the namespace clean.

```
class InputFileAction(argparse.Action):
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        if values.endswith(".ttf"):
            dest = "ttf_file"
        elif values.endswith(".xml"):
            dest = "xml_file"
        else:
            raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError("File must have .ttf or .xml extension")

        setattr(namespace, dest, values)
        delattr(namespace, self.dest)


p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
p.add_argument("input1", action=InputFileAction)
p.add_argument("input2", action=InputFileAction)
```

Some examples:

```
>>> p.parse_args(["foo.ttf", "foo.xml"])
Namespace(ttf_file='foo.ttf', xml_file='foo.xml')
>>> p.parse_args(["foo.xml", "foo.ttf"])
Namespace(ttf_file='foo.ttf', xml_file='foo.xml')
```